# Eclipse WTP HTML auto-indent

Tags: html, eclipse, indentation, eclipse-wtp

In eclipse, html file doesn't work auto-indent!
I type  and enter, than tab is correct. but not tab.
How do I do?

Comment: `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `F`

Comment: What was the previous line's indentation?

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + F, than tab is fade away. T.T

Comment: I want to coding like this...\n
<html>\n
\t<head>\n
\t\t<title>title</title>\n
\t</head>\n
</html>
but editor coding like this
<html>\n
<head>\n
<title>title</title>\n
</head>\n
</html>

Comment: result:editor does not insert '\t'